# Is there a way to change a chrome shortcut icon?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, 22.04

I want to change the icon of a desktop shortcut created from Chrome Menu -> More Tools -> Create shortcut. But changing it on the desktop file does not modifies the icon on gnome menu. Is there a way to do this?